# async.each confusion in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm taking my first steps in NodeJS, and I'm having an issue with the async-module. I had the following code which works fine:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

function load_albums(callback) {
    fs.readdir("albums", function(err, content) {
        console.log(content);
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        var directories = [];

        (function iterator(index) {
            if(index == content.length) {
                callback(null, directories);
                return;
            }
            fs.stat("albums/" + content[index], function(err, stats) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
                if(stats.isDirectory()) {
                    directories.push(content[index]);
                }
                console.log(index);
                iterator(index + 1);
            });
        })(0);
    });
}

function handle_request(request, response) {
    load_albums(function(err, albums) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(503, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(err) + "\n");
            return;
        }
        var out = { error: null,
                    data: { albums: albums}};
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
        response.end(JSON.stringify(out) + "\n");
    });
}

var s = http.createServer(handle_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

This works fine, and gives the expected output:

```
{"error":null,"data":{"albums":["testdir1","testdir2"]}}
```

However, I intended to replace the iterator with the async.each function.

I ended up with this:

```
function load_albums(callback) {
    fs.readdir("albums", function(err, content) {
        console.log(content);
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        var directories = [];
        async.each(content, function(item, callback2) {
            fs.stat("albums/" + item, function(err,stats) {
                if(stats.isDirectory()) {
                    directories.push(item);
                }
                callback2();
            });
        });
        callback(null, directories);
    });
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as "albums" seems to be empty now:

```
{"error":null,"data":{"albums":[]}}
```

What am I missing here? I guess it has something to do with calling the fs.stats() function, but I'm unsure about what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.each()` takes three arguments.  You are not passing the last one which is the one that tells you when it is done.  You also haven't implemented error handling on `fs.stat()`. You can change to this:

```
function load_albums(callback) {
    fs.readdir("albums", function(err, content) {
        console.log(content);
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        var directories = [];
        async.each(content, function(item, callback2) {
            fs.stat("albums/" + item, function(err,stats) {
                if (!err && stats.isDirectory()) {
                    directories.push(item);
                }
                callback2(err);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            callback(err, directories);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly. Have a happy 2016!

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @jfriend00 final callback is third parameter of `asyn.each`. Currently this callback is running without waiting for `async.each` to complete.

Also you're serving albums for all the request. They should be served on a particular resource URL like `/albums` or `/albums/`

I have made these modifications to the code, now it loads albums on `http://localhost:8080/albums` otherwise it returns '`No Content`.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

function load_albums(loadCompleteCallback) {
    fs.readdir("albums", function(err, content) {
        console.log(content);
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        var directories = [];

        async.each(content, function(item, doneCallback) {
            fs.stat("albums/" + item, function(err,stats) {
                if(stats.isDirectory()) {
                    directories.push(item);
                }
                return doneCallback(err);
            });
        }
        , function (err) {
            loadCompleteCallback(err, directories);
        });
    });
}
function handle_request(request, response) {
    console.log("requested path: " + request.url);
    if(request.url.match(/^\/albums[\/]?$/) ) {
        load_albums(function(err, albums) {
            if (err) {
                response.writeHead(503, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(err) + "\n");
                return;
            }
            var out = { error: null,
                        data: { albums: albums}};
            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
            response.end(JSON.stringify(out) + "\n");
        });
    } else {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
        response.end("No Content\n");
    }
}

var s = http.createServer(handle_request);
s.listen(8080);
console.log("server running at : http://localhost:" + 8080);
```